# Logging into a webpage via HTTP Request

Tags: http, authentication, request

So I have a webpage, ("http://data.terapeak.com/verify/") and I don't see any & tags in the URL so I am unaware how to post data to this. I need to do this via HTTPRequest rather than browser control. I am creating a double threaded batch searching program. I have already successfully made this using a single browser control but that wont allow for multi-threading, atleast with my current knowledge due to the fact that even when creating a new frmBrw that already exists it needs for me to set the threat apartment to single. If i set it to single, I am unable to have it send the data the the excel sheet I need both threads to access. I hope this is clear... The basic question is how can I log into this form via HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't going to be easy to answer without further details however I suspect you'll need to provide the variables via a HTTP POST request.

Can you successfully login to this page in your browser? If so, run a proxy tool such as fiddler and check the HTTP headers it makes to the server. You should see the form variables being passed over. You then need to mimic this in code.

[How to: Send Data Using the WebRequest Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx)

Hope this gets you started